# identificación de roles de usuario en mvc c#

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, mvc

Hola a todos estoy haciendo un login en mvc c# usando la base de datos sql server pero quiero hacer una validación de distintos usuarios es decir que de un usuario admin va entrar a una vista, otro usuario que seria super admin va entrar a otra vista, pero estos usuarios los llamo por medio del rol pero cuando o ejecuto me sale un error de que Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.' que el usuario es nulo pero noce que mas me este faltando o que estoy poniendo mal y esto es lo que llevo al momento en el controlador:

```
public ActionResult Login(string usuario, string contraseña, string roles)
            {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(contraseña))
            {
                ReportesContex db = new ReportesContex();
                var user = db.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(e => e.numeroUsuario == usuario && e.contraseña == contraseña && e.rol == roles);                   
                    if (user.rol != "admin") { 
                    
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.rol, true);
                        Session["nombre"] = user.nombre;
                        Session["apellidos"] = user.apellidos;
                        return RedirectToAction("IndexAdmin", "Home");

                    }
                    if (user.rol != "superAdmin")
                    {    
                        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.rol, true);
                        Session["nombre"] = user.nombre;
                        Session["apellidos"] = user.apellidos;
                        return RedirectToAction("IndexSuperAdmin", "Home");   
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        return RedirectToAction("Login", new { message = "No reconocemos tus datos" });

                    }

                }
            
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", new { message = "Llena todos los campos para poder iniciar secion" });


            }
            }

        public ActionResult IndexAdmin()
            {

                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                return Login();
            }           
        public ActionResult IndexSuperAdmin()
        {

            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return Login();
        }
```

y esto es lo que tengo en mi modelo:

```
   public class Usuarios
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string apellidos { get; set; }
        public string rol { get; set; }
        public string numeroUsuario { get; set; }
        public string contraseña { get; set; }
        public string correo { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Imagen"), DataType(DataType.Upload)]
        public byte[] firma { get; set; }
        public bool estatus { get; set; }

        public Area Area { get; set; }
}
```

y este es el error al momento de ejecutar el programa

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Crees que puedas agregar el detalle del error?

Comment: si claro deja pongo una imagen

Comment: listo ahi esta el error que me arroja cuando ejecuto el programa

Comment: No estas obteniendo ningun usuario, quita && e.rol == roles en la condicion

Comment: ya quite esa parte pero no esta entrando lo que seria al segundo rol a la vista indesusperadmin si no entra en la primera vista

Comment: pero persiste el error?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120776/discussion-between-miguel-zarate-and-fatima-jimenez-sandoval).